# How to disable non-exe extensions from running?

Tags: windows-8.1, security

I want to make my system unable to launch .scr .pif (and all executable windows formats here) as a executable program. How do I disable them an make .exe files only runnable as programs (and .msi & .bat ofcourse shall remain possible to launch).

Comment: If you might need a list of all extensions to answer this question, please reffer here: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/a/execfileext.htm

Comment: Did you try deleting `HKCR\.scr` (and same for the others) from the registry?

Comment: ah that seems to work!

Comment: Please use that as the answer :) (and remember to tell users to backup their registry)

Comment: Edit: hm this doesn't disable command line from running it, only explorer :(

Comment: Yes, it's a very crude way of doing it so I'm not adding it as an answer. It will stop users who're not very tech-savvy though. Edit: You should have mentioned that your intent was to stop malware, not users, from executing these file types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Software Restriction Policies: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457006.aspx

[image: Software Restriction Policie]

How ever, nothing prevents user from renaming file. You may also try AppLocker (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424371(v=ws.10).aspx) which is more powerful than SRP, but renaming is still possible.

Comment: +1 This is the proper way of setting up a security policy but as you said, unless all executable file types are disallowed it would be trivial to rename the SCR as an EXE and run it.

Answer (score 0):

Although Karan's comment to your post about removing `HKCR\.scr` *will* work, it is easy to bypass.  All one would have to do is rename `mystify.scr` to `mystify.exe` and it will run.  FYI, Windows screensavers are really just `.exe` executable files.

The only real way to stop executables (like .exe) from running, is to disable the `Read & Execute` permission from the security tab on it's file properties.  This can be modified by user or group.

Comment: most maliscious programs use extensions like .pif and .scr, .com, etc.. I would like only .exe's and .msi to be launchable system-wide (even if a user doesn't purposefully launch a file)

Comment: @Gizmo - But those users can still rename the files.  I can't say not allowing this extensions isn't a good idea but easily bypassed and only protects you from a small subset of the threats.  Easier to setup up your domain, so any executable downloaded, cannot be executed or better yet block it at your firewall.